# docker-compose doesnt launch more than approx. 50 service containers of 130 defined in file

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I extended my service which should now launch 130 docker containers instead of 40 (before).
however, after about 50 containers, docker-compose just stops launching more but does not show an error message. (both 2.4 and 3.7 version)

I found a work around by splitting the docker-compose files with 50 each. But this is not very elegant.

Is there a setting or a way to solve this and launch 130 containers from just 1 docker-compose file?

Here is the compose file with 2/140 sample services.

```
docker-compose version 1.23.1, build b02f1306
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "2.4"

networks:
  proxy-tier:
    external:
      name: nginx-proxy

volumes:
  data:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: 'none'
      o: 'bind'
      device: '/home/geoFrontend2'
  logs:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: 'none'
      o: 'bind'
      device: '/home/logs_geoFrontend'
  ancestors:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: 'none'
      o: 'bind'
      device: '/home/ancestors'

services:
  myapp_4:
    extends:
      file: utils.yml
      service: shiny-server
    ports:
      - "3004:3838"
    environment:
      - "VIRTUAL_PORT=3004"
      - "VIRTUAL_HOST=myapp4.mydomain.com"
  myapp_5:
    extends:
      file: utils.yml
      service: shiny-server
    ports:
      - "3005:3838"
    environment:
      - "VIRTUAL_PORT=3005"
      - "VIRTUAL_HOST=myapp5.mydomain.com"
```

utils.yml

```
version: "2.4"

networks:
  proxy-tier:
    external:
      name: nginx-proxy

services:
  shiny-server:
    image: shiny:latest
    environment:
      - "VIRTUAL_NETWORK=nginx-proxy"
    volumes:
      - data:/srv/shiny-server/
      - logs:/var/log/shiny-server/
      - ancestors:/srv/shiny-server/www/ancestors/
    networks:
      - proxy-tier
    restart: always
    mem_limit: 500m
    mem_reservation: 100m
```

Comment: check if you have a limit on the network? ie what class are you using?

Comment: @Al-waleedShihadeh thanks, how can I check the limit of the network? in the nginx proxy conf?

Comment: `docker network inspect ${network_id} | grep Subnet`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was

```
export COMPOSE_HTTP_TIMEOUT=300000
```